# How to select welded elements with marked seams

Tags: modeling

I'm using Blender 2.8, but I don't think this matters.

Is there any way to select an entire element of a single object (as key L does) that has various marked UV seams? It appears as though marked seams create breaks in the element connection just as if those edges were disconnected.

This means that if an object is broken into many UV islands, there is no longer a way to select it in a single click? Perhaps there is some way to customize the function of the "select linked" command?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you use the Linked select, on the (T) toolbar popup you can choose what kind of link you want to use.

[image: link select menu]

If this menu is collapsed there is a + tab that can open it back up on the bottom of the toolbar.

Blender usually automatically sets it to the Seam selection once you've unwrapped your object, but you can [shift]+[click] any of the options to turn them on and off. (If you know programming, this is an AND function; it will only select something that fulfills all of those selections.)

Comment: Thank you Toadhands. That is great. I just noticed the pop pup system existed this morning, but didn't realize there would be one for link selections.

I also figured out that switching to vertex mode and using select linked (L key) will ignore UV-seams as well.